# Why keep stores untouchable from the action creator on Facebook Flux?

Tags: facebook, store, flux

I'm reading about the Facebook Flux and I liked the pattern, but I don't understand why we need keep the store untouchable from the action creator. Facebook only says that it's part of "concern separation" and only the store should know how modify itself. Facebook disagrees with store setters like "setAsRead", but doesn't triggering an event on the action creator through the dispatcher that are captured on the store almost the same thing? And calling something like "setAsRead" doesn't exposes how the store are modifying itself.

Some guys say it causes coupling between the store and action creator, but triggering events on the dispatcher causes coupling between the pub/sub, store and action creator.

Keeping the stores untouchable from the action creator creates the need of the "waitFor". Wait For chains doesn't create more implicit coupling between stores? If some action need stores interacting on some given order why doesn't already make this on the action creator?

Do you guys know the cons to adopt a dispatchless approach with Facebook Flux?

Answer (score 0):

If you implement setters in your store, you would completely break the uni-directional data flow principle that is arguably the central principle of the [Flux pattern](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html). Nothing would stop your components, or any other code, from directly manipulating the store's state. Now data mutations no longer come from only stores reacting to actions, so you have many "sources of truth".

The uni-directional data flow principle is as follows, very simplified for the purpose of this discussion:

```
Actions ----> Stores ----> Components
   ^                           |
   |___________________________|
```

`waitFor` actually does create a coupling between stores, and it leaks into the Dispatcher which has to provide the `waitFor` function. It's arguably one of the more contended points of the "vanilla" Flux pattern, and for example [Reflux](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs) implements it differently, without a central dispatcher.